# Positioning of 2 relative images with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, resizable

I have a picture with a max-width of 1200px and a relative width of 85%.
On top of this picture I have another one, which is a small part of the first picture. This second one I'd like to use as a link, that's why I cut it out of the first one and placed it on top.

I'm using absolute values for positioning, but however i adjust the values, it only fits at one specific point when resizing the viewport.

I want to use several parts of the image as links (sort of like a menu), in the enclosed code - for simplicity - there's only one image as link.

I'm trying to do something [like this](http://retroactif.free.fr/dran/) but with resizable images.

My code is below and this is what it looks like now with the images: [Link with the images](http://www.plein.ch)

Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks a lot!

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 background: black; 
}
div#bgrImg {  /* div with the background image */
 max-width: 1200px;
 width: 85%; 
 /* margin: 5% auto 0 auto; */
 position: absolute;
 left: 7.5%;
 top: 8.3%;
}
#bgrImg img { /* the background image */
 width: 100%; 
}
div#signLink { /* div with the sign image */
 max-width: 1200px;
 width: 85%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 7.5%;
 top: 26%;
}
#signLink img { /* the sign image */
 width: 22%;
 position:absolute;
 left: 51.5%;
}
#signLink:hover {
 cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="bgrImg">
 <img src="_images/hillBgr.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="signLink">
<a href="index.htm"><img src="_images/hillSign.png"/></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to look into `<map>` & `<area>` for this. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

Comment: You do not need to use a cut-out of an existing image to be able to use it as a link; rather use maps, as quoted in the comment above. Further relevant information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778589/non-rectangular-css-image-links (don't say this link is off-topic just because of the conflicting title, but instead take time to read it)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but after reading through the suggested articles I think this is not the right solution for me, since <area> can't be styled with CSS. I need to style the areas, e.g. hover effects... i read that svg could be a solution, but I have no idea where to start there... again, any suggestions would be much appreciated!! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with SVG. In Adobe Illustrator (or any other vector software) I saved my images as .svg. 
In the .svg file i drew a vector path over the part of the image I want to use as a hotspot link. After saving that, when I open the .svg file in a text editor, below the image-tag there's a path-tag, which defines, where the 'hotspot-layer' on the image is.
The whole xml code of the svg can be copied from the svg file into the HTML. Example below.
I'm really not an expert at this, and maybe there's unnecessary stuff in the code, but this worked perfectly for me, the svg-hotspot scales with the image and can be styled with CSS.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>svg mapping</title>
</head>

<body>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="-359 46.36 480 308.64" style="enable-background:new -359 46.36 480 308.64;" xml:space="preserve">
    <image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new    ;" width="2000" height="1288" xlink:href="yourImage.jpg" transform="matrix(0.24 0 0 0.2396 -359 46.36)">
    </image>
    <a xlink:href="https://www.yoursite.com">
        <path style="opacity:0;fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M-35.042,281.926c0,0,6.346,1.664,8.53-0.936s0.312-12.067,1.456-18.308
            c1.144-6.241,6.45-20.181,10.506-22.261c4.057-2.08,6.241-3.849,8.53-3.849s5.825-0.104,7.282-1.664
            c1.456-1.56,3.641-4.889,2.08-8.01s-2.08-8.114-5.201-8.842c-3.121-0.728-3.121-0.728-3.121-0.728s-3.953,1.04-5.305,0
            c-1.352-1.04-14.459-16.228-24.03-14.563s-17.684,2.08-20.909,9.674c-3.225,7.594-2.393,11.339-0.936,16.956
            c1.456,5.617,2.601,12.795,1.352,15.812c-1.248,3.017-4.057,12.483-1.248,17.684C-53.246,268.09-51.582,276.204-35.042,281.926z"/>
    </a>
</svg>


</body>
</html>
```